# Connect to local database (windows) from Ubuntu linux virtual machine

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to connect to my local windows database server from Ubuntu Linux Virtual machine.
I've created a user and grants in the database and flushed the privileges.
However when trying to connect to the db from the virtual machine using 'mysql -h <ipv4_local_address> -P 3306 -u  -p' , the connection times out as it is unable to connect.
ufw status shows inactive.

Comment: Did you actually enable networking in the DB server?

Comment: Yes, I have. I was able to connect to the db from wsl ubuntu linux. But for the virtual machine it fails